# How do I get the event time from an event click in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, momentjs

I have an eventclick event in fullcalendar and it returns the details about the event which includes the date and time. How do I just get the time? ex 6:00:00 am

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jRFYE/450/) I'm using.

I'm trying .time() because the documentation says [start](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) is a moment like object and the moment object has a method called [.time()](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/Moment/)

```
eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) { 
        alert(calEvent.start.time());
    }
```

Comment: the first arg appears to be a Date object

Comment: According to the docs `.time()` returns the duration, not the starting time. So, try `calEvent.start.format('h:mm:ss a')`

Answer (score 10):

You need to install the plugin `moment.js`

Than you can use

`eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) { 
     alert(moment(calEvent.start).format('h:mm:ss a'));
 }`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jRFYE/457/)

Comment: moment.js is already part of FullCalender and most times are moment.js-objects

Answer (score 0):

The current version of FullCalendar ([2.4.0](http://fullcalendar.io/download/)) gets shipped with [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) which is an extensive library to parse, manipulate and format dates. But in your fiddle, you're using FullCalendar 1.5.3 which is slightly older and doesn't include moment.js.

You linked [the official docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/Moment/), but beware, they're for the current version, not your old one! In your FullCalendar, `calEvent.start` is a standard [JS Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), so you can use the standard Date methods to get the time:

```
eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) { 
    alert(calEvent.start.getHours()+':'+calEvent.start.getMinutes()+':'+calEvent.start.getSeconds());
    // displays 10:30:0
}
```

In your Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jRFYE/471/

If you want to switch to the current version of FullCalendar, you can use the moment.js methods. I updated your Fiddle [to the latest version of FullCalendar](https://jsfiddle.net/a8ett4uz/), here you can format the time in a more extensive way:

```
eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) { 
    alert(calEvent.start.format('h:mm:ss a'));
    // displays 10:30:00 am
}
```